# How can we set the Header of CellTable Dynamically?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I just want to set the Header text of every column dynamically.

```
|Header1|Header2|Header3|

-------------------------------------------------------
|    ROW 1 
----------------------------------------------------
|    ROW 2
```

I need to set Header1,Header2,Header3 dynamically. For ex.

```
final TextColumn<Contacts> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contacts>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Contacts contact) {
            return contact.name();
        }
    };
cellTable.addColumn(nameColumn, contact.city());
```

Like this (contact.city()) i've to set the Header text from the Server response.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by the following code.
 Let us consider `List<Contacts>` return from the server.

```
where response is List<Contacts>

      for (Contacts contact : response) {
           final String name = contact.getName();
           final TextColumn<Contacts> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contacts>() {

            @Override
            public String getValue(Contacts object) {
                return name;
            }
        };

        cellTable.addColumn(addressColumn, contact.getCity());
        }
```

Regards, Gnik